# Get CorId/Msg Id in Websphere MQ C++

Tags: c++, ibm-mq, mq

Is there a way to get the Correlation Id/ Message Id and store it into the variable? I want to put it into a variable and store it into the database.

I'm thinking of using MQMD.

**MQMD *md;**

**std::string corid = md->CorrelId;**

*The code above is not functioning.*

Please help me with this. BTW, I'm using Websphere MQ for C++.

Thanks! :)

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940046/correlation-id-websphere-mq-c in which the response was essentially "you can't do that because those fields are binary and should not be coerced into strings."

Comment: Sorry T.Rob I think I lack some statement to my last post. I think I get what I want for this "correlID puzzel". Thanks for the effort! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MessageID, CorrelID and GroupID are all byte arrays. Hence they can't be assigned the way you are trying to. Instead do the following to get messageID. You can try out similarly for CorrelationID and GroupID.

```
  if ( queue.get( msg, gmo ) ) 
  {
      // Get the message id 
      char byMessageId[24];
      ImqBinary msglId = msg.messageId();

      // Copy the message to a buffer.
      msglId.copyOut(byMessageId,24);
  }
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: I will try it and let you know, by the way thanks for the help! :)

Comment: works like a charm, thanks! :)

I just added some codes to get what output I want.